# When in the presence of multiple people, is it preferred to use people's first name when referring to them vs a pronoun?

Tags: conversation, names

I saw an interview with Russel Brand on Youtube where he notes that you should not refer to someone, who is present, using their pronoun but their actual name as that is good manners:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sj6JdXvsWYM&t=370s

What is the guidance here?

Answer (score 2):

There is a long tradition, at least in the UK, of reproaching a child who refers to an adult as *she* with the question "Who's 'she'? The cat's mother?" (Discussed [here](https://languagehat.com/the-cats-mother/)).

I've never heard a corresponding expression for *he*, but the same issue of politeness applies.

Comment: I was taught as a child never to refer to an adult by his or her first name--we were to say Mister ___ or Missus ____ (and the surname).  In fact, I often did not know the adult's first name, as it was not included in the introductions.

Comment: I think it's primarily a *British* usage, but I sometimes hear [***Does he take sugar?***](https://www.physiopod.co.uk/does-he-take-sugar.shtml) (originating in the context of handicapped people) used with a similar sense in more general contexts today. @Biblasia - no-one is suggesting that just because politeness sometimes dictates that we shouldn't refer to someone who's physically present using a 3rd person singular pronoun, that doesn't license disrespectfully using their first name (if you're not *actually* on "first name terms" with them, whatever the respective ages).

Comment: As I've grown up, I've tried to learn people's names and remember them as a very simple way to show respect. In conversation where three or more poeple are present, it ensures a much more accurate dialogue.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Being a child, it would have been less respectful to use an adult's first name than to use a pronoun.  I was never instructed as a child not to use a pronoun for someone.  Is this because I did not grow up in England?

Comment: @Biblasia:  The reason for not using using a person's given (first) name (to address them *or* refer to them) is that it's "presumptuous" if that person hasn't explicitly given you permission to do so. Which will more often apply if you're a child and the other person is an adult, but that's not what it turns on. The reason for not using ***she*** (and possibly ***he***) is more subtle - it's closely connected to my *Does he take sugar?* alternative, but note that not all Anglophones recognize this particular convention of polite social interaction.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't even understand the "Does he take sugar?" idiom--I don't think I've ever heard it.  What is meant by this?

Comment: I assume you haven't followed Kate's link in her answer, or the one in my first comment. Briefly, if three people X, Y, and Z are "conversing", but most of the talking is being done by X and Y (for *whatever* reason), then from Z's point of view it will often feel that she's being excluded from the conversation if the other two keep referring to her as ***she*** (which they would quite naturally do if Z wasn't actually present). Russell Brand is one of those people who can "dominate" a conversation, so he in particular might need to be more aware of this than most.

Comment: @Biblasia - Yes, when I was young (_many_ years ago!) it was considered bad manners for a child to use an adult's given name, but that is a different issue. It's about making a statement about someone, especially in their presence, without using their name. (The _Does he take sugar?_ thing is about treating a disabled person as though they can't speak for themselves.)

Answer (score 0):

In the US, it is not disrespectful to refer to someone as “he” or “she” in their presence, unless you are misgendering them (which is why some people announce their pronouns upfront).

The bigger concern for me would be ambiguity. If you motion to a group of five guys and say “He has a question,” it might not be clear which one you are talking about. If there is a risk of ambiguity, you should use their name.